# Backup Manager and Cron : CentOs and Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: backup, ftp, php

I have two dedicated servers: one has CentOS, the other Ubuntu. I installed backup manager on both servers. But I have two different behaviors.

On CentOS:

- The backup of my files is "every night". I wish "every week."
- The backup of my DB is "every night" (that's good).
- the action is executed twice each night (once at 2 am, once at 4am ... why??)
- Backup Manager for erase on my FTP files older than 5 days ... So, this morning, my backup server was completely full.

On Ubuntu:

- The backup does not start automatically. Why?
- When I start it manually, it seems to work but I get an error. In fact, I use a PHP script that fires when Backup Manager has completed. My script detects file integrity with md5 checksum. But there seems to be an error.

Here is my [backup-manager.conf on CentOS](http://itbag.fr/stack/backup-manager.conf.txt)

Here is my [post-backup script for CentOS](http://itbag.fr/stack/backup-manager-post.txt)

- It does not use the checksum
- It works
- However, I do not find the hostname: why??
- The mail is sent like this:

  ```
  Ns390769.ovh.net-sacdunjour.20111115.sql.gz (0.08 GB)
  nns390769.ovh.net-www.20111115.tar.gz (0.01 GB)
  nns390769.ovh.net-www.20111115.master.tar.gz (1.65 GB)
  nns390769.ovh.net-20111115.md5 (0 GB) nns390769.ovh.net-itbag_prestashop.20111115.sql.gz (0 GB) 
  nTotal: 1.74 Go
  ```

Here is my [backup-manager.conf on ubuntu](http://bobcat.pro/stack/backup-manager.conf.txt)

Here is my [post-backup script on ubuntu](http://bobcat.pro/stack/backup-manager-post.txt)

- Use of checksum
- It does not find me the file size
- I find the hostname (not CentOS)
- The mail is sent like this

  ```
  Files locally:

  Ns384990.ovh.net-20111108.md5 (0 B)
  Ns384990.ovh.net-all-mysql-databases.20111108.sql.bz2 (0 B)
  Ns384990.ovh.netwww.20111108.master.tar.gz (0 B)

  TOTAL: 0 B
  Integrity problem in the files sent to the FTP server`
  ```

It's a real headache for me. Can you help me?

Sorry for the length of my message, but I wanted to give you much information.

Comment: Eh, there are way too many differences in the scripts (they don't look the same at all) and the backup configuration files look very different too (sections don't even appear to be in the same order). Why don't you first try and make the scripts and configuration as similar as possible?

Comment: I install backup-manager with rpm (on CentOS) and apt-get install (on ubuntu). I don't know if I can erase the ubuntu backup-manager conf file with the centOs backup-manger conf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just re-installed and everything works. This is clearer.